# Problem with CSS style on formtastic buttons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, formtastic

If i have a formtastic button with a CSS override like this:

```
-f.buttons do
  =f.commit_button :button_html => { :class => 'button positive' }
```

I am seeing the rendered style as "button positive update" in the browser. How do I get it to only reflect the CSS class that I want to use and dump the "update" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No can do, it's [part of formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/helpers/buttons_helper.rb#L265)

```
button_html.merge!(:class => [button_html[:class], key].compact.join(' '))
```

The `key` in there is the 'create' or 'update' string.